# Reformat Hibernated NTFS Partition or Whole Drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ntfs

I've been having a lot of issues with my system, which is dual-booted Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16. My Ubuntu installation is on a HDD, while windows is on an SSD.

Recently my Windows installation has stopped working... some extra details are available here, but I've given up on fixing the core problem with Windows:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/login-options-missing/ab1d7ba3-4aba-46df-bea5-4bf52a8c069a?auth=1&rtAction=1577667725471

The short of it is that Windows will still boot but I can't log in to any accounts (which means I can't do things like disabling hibernation or fast restart). I've spent a lot of time trying unsuccessfully to repair the system using the in-built recovery options and also a windows recovery USB.

Ubuntu still works fine and I'm able to mount the drive read-only. I've backed up everything I care about. I now just want to wipe the drive and reinstall Windows from scratch. I can't seem to do this with any of the options in either Ubuntu or the Windows recovery USB, though.

### Some things I've tried:

1) Windows Recovery USB - advanced custom install -> delete partition: this hung for several seconds and then reloaded the partition list with nothing changed, and provided no error message.

2) Windows Recovery USB - advanced custom install -> format partition: this gives the error message: "We couldn't format the selected partition. [Error: 0x80042428]

3) Windows Recovery USB -> shift+f10 into cmd prompt -> DISKPART -> del part: this runs but doesn't make any actual change to the partition list

4) Windows Recovery USB -> shift+f10 into cmd prompt -> DISKPART -> clean all: attempting to clean the entire SSD this way fails with the message "Access is denied."

5) Ubuntu -> GParted -> reformat as ntfs (or any other format): this runs and throws no errors but makes no change to the partition table

6) Ubuntu -> GParted -> delete partition: this runs and throws no errors but makes no change to the partition table

7) Ubuntu -> sudo fdisk /dev/drivename -> d drivenum -> w: this throws the following error: "Re-reading the partition table failed.: Device or resource busy. The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)."

8) Ubuntu -> disks utility -> delete or reformat partition, or rewrite partition table (as GPT) -> all of these have the same non-effect as using GParted. The GUI will act as though it is performing the action but nothing will actually change in the partition table.

9) Ubuntu -> sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /partitionname /media/windows -o remove_hiberfile

[image]

10) Ubuntu -> sudo ntfsfix /parititionname

[image]

I've also tried all the Ubuntu options above using a Ubuntu installation USB (rather than the actual Ubuntu installation on the HDD).

Even after all these attempts at deleting/reformatting the partition, I'm still able to read-only mount the partition, and I can see that no changes have actually been made to the file system (everything's still there).

I'm at wits' end here. I want to emphasize that I don't actually want to recover this Windows install, I just want to reformat the drive and reinstall from scratch - but I can't figure out how to do this. I'm posting this here in the Ubuntu forum because I am looking for options to use Ubuntu to force a reformatting of the partition or drive.

Comment: `gparted` won't update a partition if ANY partition on that disk is mounted. Inspect the logs! `man journalctl`, `sudo journalctl -b 0` to page through the logs of the current boot,

Comment: I don't think disks being mounted is the problem. For one thing, the ubuntu recovery USB shouldn't be mounting any of the drives by default, and gparted fails there the same was as on the main installation. Running:
`sudo journalctl -b 0 | grep 'nvme'`
doesn't return any mount commands (the disk name is nvme0n1)

Comment: If I actually do mount the drive as read-only (e.g. `sudo mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p4 /media/windows`) the command shows up in the journalctl logs afterwards, but it isn't there on an initial boot and the gparted changes still don't work in that case.

Comment: Use `gparted` to install a fresh GPT partition table, and that will wipe the drive so you can reinstall Windows.

Comment: Hi heynnema, thanks for your reply - I mentioned above that this doesn't work.